# How to use Ruby code inside JST files?

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, jammit

I am using Jammit to package my assets. One of the things it does well is package files with .jst extension and make them available in window.jst namespace in the browser. However, I've been looking for a way to make those templates dynamic, and I'm not sure how to do that or if it's even possible.

What alternatives do I have if I cannot make JST files dynamic?

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell with Rails 3.0 it isn't possible. Jammit assumes the JST files are JavaScript files. Maybe in later versions they may add the ability. But I wouldn't count on it happening any time soon.

If you are able to upgrade to Rails 3.1 you can replace Jammit with the Asset Pipeline that allows you to run it through ERB or what ever language you want before it ends up as a JST file.

Kliment Mamykin made a walkthrough to upgrade from Rails 3.0 to Rails 3.1.rc4 with Asset Pipeline enabled.
http://mamykin.com/2011/07/03/upgrading-to-rails31-rc4.html

Comment: Nice! I'm going to give that a try. Thanks.

Comment: On the other hand...moving away from Jammit is a huge thing. I wish there was a middle way.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there isn't a good way to test JavaScript files through the Asset Pipeline at the moment. But I'm sure it's bugging enough developers and I hope a solution will come up sooner or later.